# Reset an NSTimer's firing time to be from now instead of the last fire

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have a `NSTimer` that fires with an interval of 3 seconds to decrease a value. When I do an action that increases that value, I want to restart the timer to count 3 seconds from that point.

For example, if I increase the value and timer will fires in 1 second, I want to change that and make the timer fire in 3 seconds instead. Can I invalidate the timer and create it again? Or can I do it with `setFireDate:`, using the current date and adding an interval of 3 seconds?

Comment: Finally I use setFireWithDate, when I increase the value I also send a message to the timer with current date plus three seconds. It works ^^

Thank you very much at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can invalidate it.  And create it again.

You can also use:

```
- (void) myTimedTask {
    // other stuff this task needs to do

    // change the variable varyingDelay to be 1s or 3s or...  This can be an instance variable or global that is changed by other parts of your app
    // weStillWantTimer is also a similar variable that your app uses to stop this recurring task

if (weStillWantTimer)
       [self performSelector:@selector(myTimedTask:) withObject:gameColor afterDelay:varyingDelay];

 }
```

You call myTimedTask to start the recurring task.  Once it is started, you can change the delay with varyingDelay or stop it with weStillWantTimer.

Comment: @zoul, depends on how messy you want to be :-)

Answer (score 4):

I've done a little testing, and it turns out that resetting the fireDate is about four times faster than invalidating and re-creating the timer. First, I create a timer which calls the method doNothing:

```
if (!testTimer) {
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                                      target:self
                                                    selector:@selector(doNothing:)
                                                    userInfo:nil
                                                     repeats:NO];
    testTimer   = timer;
}
```

Here is the test code:

```
- (void) testInvalidatingTimer {
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
        [testTimer invalidate];
        testTimer = nil;

        NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0
                                                          target:self
                                                        selector:@selector(doNothing:)
                                                        userInfo:nil
                                                         repeats:NO];
        testTimer   = timer;
    }
}

- (void) testResettingTimer {
    for (int n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
        if ([testTimer isValid]) {
            testTimer.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:3.0];
        }
    }
}
```

Running that on an iPad Air yields 0.198173 s for invalidatingTimer and 0.044207 s for resettingTimer. If performance is your target, I recommend to reset the fireDate. It is also quite a bit less coding effort.

Answer (score 1):

Invalidate the timer and recreate it.  However, make sure you don't invalidate *and* release the timer unless you are sure you need to since the run loop retains timers until they are invalidated and then releases them itself.

In my opinion mixing -performSelector code with timer code leads to multiple execution of the target methods, so I'd stay away from that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, invalidating and recreating the timer will work.  It is essentially what you are wanting to do if you are not increasing your value: reset and start over.

Answer (score 1):

The [`setFireDate:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000319-BBCCEHJG) docs mention that changing the fire date is relatively expensive, suggesting that it may be better to destroy and recreate the timer unless you're doing so *a lot*. For the sake of argument, however, I whipped up this category a little while ago. I prefer this because it encapsulates the date adjustment behavior; the timer itself handles it, rather than its owner/controller. I don't have any performance data on this, though.

```
@implementation NSTimer (WSSAdjustingFireDate)

- (void)WSSFireAdjustingFireDate
{
    [self fire];

    [self WSSSkipNextFireAdjustingFireDate];
}

- (void)WSSSkipNextFireAdjustingFireDate
{
    CFRunLoopTimerRef cfSelf = (__bridge CFRunLoopTimerRef)self;
    CFTimeInterval delay = CFRunLoopTimerGetInterval(cfSelf);
    CFRunLoopTimerSetNextFireDate(cfSelf, CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() + delay);
}

@end
```

I've used the Core Foundation functions just to avoid creating an `NSDate`. Premature optimization? Please pass the salt.