# Changing the interval of an NSTimer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstimer

Can anyone tell me if it's possible to change the interval of an `NSTimer` while it's firing?

Seems like this should be possible but haven't figured out how.

Basically, I'm trying to create a deceleration effect.

Comment: This question was already asked on s.o.
Look here for a solution. (moved from answer ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restart NSTimer firing interval](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582740/restart-nstimer-firing-interval) (which is the *"here"* garph0 referred to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the timer's interval probably isn't the right way to implement a “deceleration” effect—it's better to have the timer updating at the same rate, and change whatever value it's influencing by a little less on each iteration.